# написать генератор для матрицы

Tags: python

Требуется помощь с задачкой. которая ломает мне мозг.

```
m = [[1, 2, 3],
    [4, 5, 6],
    [7, 8, 9]]
```

есть матрица и есть такой генератор:

```
[m[i][i] for i in range(len(m))]
```

который выводит результат - [1, 5, 9]

вопрос. Как написать генератор что бы он выводил результат - [3, 5, 7]
именно генератор, так как сделать прямой запрос к матрице не сложно, а создать генератор сложно)

```
m[0][2], m[1][1],m[2][0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[m[i][len(m)-i-1] for i in range(len(m))]
```

Comment: спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 1):

```
In [15]: matrix = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

In [16]: [matrix[x][-(x+1)] for x in range(len(matrix))]
Out[16]: [3, 5, 7]
```

Такой `range` выдаст нам следующие индексы:

```
[(0, -1), (1, -2), (2, -3)]
```

Comment: спасибо за решение